# Chome downloads aspx page instead of an excel like it does in IE and firefox

Tags: html, excel, google-chrome

I have a webpage that allows users to download excel reports, in Chrome, it just tries to download an aspx page instead of the excel like it successfully does in IE and Firefox.

Is this a known issue and is there a workaround?

I am using this in VB:

```
db.subRunReader(resultSQL)
dgProperties.DataSource = db.sqlReader
dgProperties.DataBind()
db.subCloseReader()
db.subCloseConnection()

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.Charset = ""
Me.EnableViewState = False

Dim tw As New System.IO.StringWriter()
Dim hw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw)
dgProperties.RenderControl(hw)
Response.Write(tw.ToString())
Response.End()
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString())
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you serving the file?

Comment: @ikh asp.net 2.0, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your specific situation, but in general whenever you want a file downloaded, it is a good idea to add a `Content-Disposition` header.  In ASP.NET MVC it would be done like this:

```
Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = 
    "attachment;filename=yourfile.xls";
```

I expect in ASP.NET 2.0 it would be something similar.  This tells the browser that it needs to download the file.

Comment: I just tried this and it fixes chrome.. and now IE downloads the aspx page. must be the right path, though... any idea why that would break IE?

Comment: That.. I did not expect.  Maybe add that response header only when a `User-Agent` request header does not contain string "MSIE"?

Comment: Alternatively, try setting `Response.ContentType` to `"application/octet-stream"`.

Comment: I did not expect it either, i was pretty thrilled it fixed it but retested on everything and found that. What is interesting is if I 'save' the file and then open it, it works. but if i 'open' the file, it trys to open the aspx page(but in excel)

I tried octet-stream to no avail, I supposed I will check the user-agent but i was hoping for something that would just work for everything. Thank you for the help nonetheless, since I had no way to get it working in chrome before.